# Bot can't send channel photo by file_id

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I use python and here is a problem. First I use method `get_chat` to get `file_id` of photo chat as example.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
s = bot.get_chat('@codygarbrandt_best')
print(s.photo.big_file_id)
```

Then I want to send this photo to myself.

```
bot.send_photo(my_chat_id , s.photo.big_file_id )
```

But I get the following error.

> Bad Request: type of file mismatch

I remember it worked before, how can I achieve this now?

Comment: What's the `type(s.photo.big_file_id)`?

Comment: its a photo type, and big_file_id of this photo

Comment: Of course that's the id of the photo... I ask about the exact type, you can check that with `print(type(s.photo.big_file_id))`.

Comment: sorry, it is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `big_file_id` which can be read from the `get_chat` method can only be used for downloading the photo. 
You will have to store the file locally yourself and then resend it.

> Unique file identifier of big (640x640) chat photo. This file_id can be used only for photo download. [[doc]](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatphoto)